# Number of times an array is present in another array in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I count the number of times an array is present in a larger array?

```
a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
b = np.array([1, 1, 1])
```

The count for the number of times b is present in a should be **3**

**b** can be any combination of 1s and 0s

I'm working with huge arrays, so for loops are pretty slow

Comment: These are lists. Please format as code and make it clear where the numpy arrays are suposed to be. Also, add a reference implementation showing how exactly you obtain the result with this small input.

Comment: SO can help you improve your code and fix problems, but it's not a free coding service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a super fast method, but you can view `a` as a windowed array using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
window = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a, b.shape)
```

You can now equate this to `b` directly and find where they match:

```
result = (window == b).all(-1).sum()
```

For older versions of numpy (pre-1.20.0), you can use [`np.libs.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) to achieve a similar result:

```
window = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
    a, shape=(*(np.array(a.shape) - b.shape + 1), *b.shape),
    strides=a.strides + (a.strides[0],) * b.ndim)
```

Comment: @rjaditya. This method is actually pretty inefficient. You are much better off using the convolution, which is elegant and fast.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The convolution method won't work if the small array contains 0s

Comment: @rjaditya. Add one to both arrays

Comment: @rjaditya See my answer for how to adapt the convolution to handle the small array containing 0s

Comment: @rjaditya See also [loopy walt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69276775/11082165) for an even simpler approach using convolution.

Answer (score 4):

If the subarray being searched for contains all 1s, you can count the number of times the subarray appears in the larger array by convolving the two arrays with [`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) and counting the number of entries in the result that equal the size of the subarray:

```
# 'valid' = convolve only over the complete overlap of the signals
>>> np.convolve(a, b, mode='valid')
array([1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1])
#               ^           ^  ^             <= Matches

>>> win_size = min(a.size, b.size)
>>> np.count_nonzero(np.convolve(a, b) == win_size)
3
```

For subarrays that may contain 0s, you can start by using convolution to transform `a` into an array containing the binary numbers encoded by each window of size `b.size`. Then just compare each element of the transformed array with the binary number encoded by `b` and count the matches:

```
>>> b = np.array([0, 1, 1])           # encodes '3'
>>> weights = 2 ** np.arange(b.size)  # == [1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 2**(b.size-1)]

>>> np.convolve(a, weights, mode='valid')
array([4, 1, 3, 7, 6, 5, 3, 7, 7, 6, 4, 1])
#            ^           ^                  Matches

>>> target = (b * np.flip(weights)).sum()  # target==3
>>> np.count_nonzero(np.convolve(a, weights, mode='valid') == target)
2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using a list comprehension:

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
b = [1, 1, 1]
sum(a[i:i+len(b)]==b for i in range(len(a)-len(b)))
```

output: `3`

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few improvements on @Brian's answer:

1. Use `np.correlate` not `np.convolve`; they are nearly identical but `convolve` reads `a` and `b` in opposite directions
2. To deal with templates that have zeros convert the zeros to -1. For example:

```
a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
b = np.array([0,1,1])
np.correlate(a,2*b-1)
# array([-1,  1,  2,  1,  0,  0,  2,  1,  1,  0, -1,  1])
```

The template fits where the correlation equals the number of ones in the template. The indices can be extracted like so:

```
(np.correlate(a,2*b-1)==np.count_nonzero(b)).nonzero()[0]
# array([2, 6])
```

If you only need the count use `np.count_nonzero`

```
np.count_nonzero((np.correlate(a,2*b-1)==np.count_nonzero(b)))
# 2
```